# Aligning images to bottom on Bootstrap page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap site with a TBS 'page-header', above which I have two images of different height, the first image is given no particular instruction, but the second image is told to float right, such that, regardless of the viewport, the first image will always be on the left and the second image will always touch the right.

The problem here is that I want to align both images to the line provided by the 'page-header' so that the bottom of each image is flush with the other and equidistant from the 'page-header' Hr, but what I'm getting is that the tops are flush with each other - ie, they're aligning to the top. I've used pull-right, vertical-align:bottom on different divs, etc. I haven't changed the Bootstrap.

I can't get it!!!

```
   <div class="row clearfix page-header">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <div>
                <a href="default.aspx">
                    <img src="img/Logo.jpg" /></a>
                <img style="float: right" src="img/cc1.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The CSS is standard Twitter Bootstrap 3.x, I haven't changed it.

Answer (score 0):

vertical-align:bottom is a bit rubbish.

What I could do is set the empty `<div>` to `position:relative`, then on the image you want at the bottom to `position:absolute; bottom:0`.